# OSX Lion Disk Mounter

Tags: macos, disk-utility, automount

I seem to have broken something in my OSX Lion install. Whenever I insert a SD/CD-ROM into the machine I have to go into Disk Util to manually mount it. This happens quite a lot and is getting on my nerves. Any ideas what I might have done or what might cause this?

Thanks

Gordon

Answer (score 1):

The launchd daemons and agents should be mounting these for you...

- com.apple.diskarbitrationd
- com.apple.diskmanagementd
- com.apple.DiskArbitrationAgent

... so unless you were editing these or your filesystem had the files go corrupt it might be faster to install Lion onto an external drive and test to see if a clean install remedies the issue.

If so, you could migrate your data to that external drive and make sure it's not a configuration issue.

If not, you could then start down a hardware isolation or repair path.